# How to insert into Java String array, how to properly find index, isAvailable boolean method, frequency of item

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm having difficulties with these methods in my code, they have to be string array unfortunately.

(some of the code I haven't got to)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortedStringArray {
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String[] list = new String[10];

    // default
    public SortedStringArray() {
        String[] list = new String[10];
    }

    // initial
    public SortedStringArray(int initialCapacity) {
        String[] list = new String[initialCapacity = input.nextInt()];
    }

    // insert
    public void insertItem(String item) {
        int i = list.length;
        int n = ++i;
        String[] list2 = new String[n];
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < list.length; cnt++) {
            list2[cnt] = list[cnt];
        }

    }

    // print
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    // isAvailable
    public boolean isAvailable(String item) {

        return true;
    }

    // get index
    public int getIndex(String item) {
        int index = -1;
        for(int i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // delete
    public void delete(int index) {
        System.out.println("Deleting an Item: ");
        String item = input.next();
        // not available
        if (list == null || index < 0 || index >= list.length) {
            System.out.println(item + " is NOT available in sorted array to delete !");
        }
        String[] list2 = new String[list.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (i == index) {
                continue;
            }
            list2[k++] = list[i];
        }

        // return array
        System.out.println(item + " is deleted from sorted string array !");
    }

    // size
    public int size() {
        return list.length;
    }
    // frequency of item

    public int frequencyOfItem(String item) {

    }
}
```

Current Sorted Array with size: 24
A A A F H H I J K K M M M N O O O Q R X X Y Z Z

Searching an Item:
G is NOT available in sorted string array

Deleting an Item:
R is deleted from sorted string array !

Current Sorted Array with size: 23
A A A F H H I J K K M M M N O O O Q X X Y Z Z

Frequency an Item:
Number of occurrence of L is 0

Comment: Why don't you use `ArrayList` instead? It's backed by an array of objects anyway. And it has most of the methods you need.

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: It's supposed to be a challenge not to use ArrayList.

Comment: A whole bunch of things, mainly how to do the isAvailable method, and frequencyOfItem method

Answer (score 1):

If this is a challenge, here're some tips:

- `isAvailable()` method - simply iterate over your array and compare Strings with `equals()` method. If you find one - return `true`, otherwise - `false`.
- `frequencyOfItem()` method - same as above, but you will also need a counter to count the number of times the `equals()` method has returned true. Simply return that number.
- `delete()` method - shift all the values on the right side of the object being removed to the left (their new indexes (i) will be i - 1). Use a field of `int` type to store the number of values in you array list. (`list.length() != size()`).
- `insertItem()`- find the right index to insert into (this is a sorted array, right?), shift all the values starting from the found index to the right (i + 1). Insert the new element at the found index. Note: you will have to rebuild the array if there's not enough space for new elements. Have a look at `Arrays.copyOf()` method.